# nginx не хочет работать на 80 порту

Tags: nginx, веб-сервер, centos7, порты, digitalocean

Если кратко, то если поставить *nginx* прослушивать 80 порт, он его прослушивает, но при открытии сайта: **connection refused**, если ставить любой другой порт, то все работает. *Apache* при этом присутствует, но выключен, и там стоит другой порт, поэтому конфликт с ним исключен. В качестве файрвола стоит **iptables**.

CentOS Linux 7.5.1804, nginx 1.15.2
Хостинг Digitalocean. Мало ли, это поможет как-то (файрвол в DO отключен).

Подробнее

**nginx.conf**

```
user  user;
worker_processes  auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile 100000;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  4096;
    multi_accept on;
}

http   {
    index         index.html index.php;
    include       mime.types;
    types { application/font-woff2; }
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" - "$request_id"';
    log_format  error403  '$remote_addr - [$time_local] "$request" "$http_user_agent" - "$request_id"';

    keepalive_timeout   5;
    autoindex       off;
    server_tokens       off;
    port_in_redirect    off;
    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    etag        off;

    client_max_body_size 64m;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;
    client_header_buffer_size 16k;
    large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;

    fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
    fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;

    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;

}
```

**default.conf**

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
        root /home/user/public_html;
        index index.html;

        location / {
             try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

**sub.domain.ru.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name sub.domain.ru;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.sub.domain.ru.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.sub.domain.ru.log  error;

    set $USER_ROOT /home/user/web/sub.domain.ru/public_html;
    root $USER_ROOT/public;

        gzip off;

    location / {
              try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

                add_header X-Processing-Time $request_time always;
                add_header X-Request-ID $request_id always;
                add_header X-UA-Compatible 'IE=Edge,chrome=1';
                add_header Link "<$scheme://$http_host$request_uri>; rel=\"canonical\"" always;

                fastcgi_pass            127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index           index.php;
                include                 fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_keep_conn       on;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

**netstat -tupln**

```
netstat -tupln
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      879/php-fpm: master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1577/mysqld
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1184/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      860/redis-server 12
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11211         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      861/memcached
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6380          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      876/redis-server 12
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      535/rpcbind
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1200/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16639/docker-proxy
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1153/master
tcp        0      0 255.255.255.255:10010    0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      15801/docker-contai
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:17000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1496/perl
tcp6       0      0 :::9443                 :::*                    LISTEN      16627/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1184/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      535/rpcbind
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1200/nginx: master
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      1153/master
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*                           533/chronyd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:702             0.0.0.0:*                           535/rpcbind
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:17000           0.0.0.0:*                           1496/perl
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*                           535/rpcbind
udp6       0      0 ::1:323                 :::*                                533/chronyd
udp6       0      0 :::702                  :::*                                535/rpcbind
udp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                                535/rpcbind
```

**iptables -L**

```
iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:8099
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:22
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:17000
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             255.255.255.255           tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             255.255.255.255           tcp dpt:http

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

IP адреса, некоторые порты и домен изменены.

Логи *nginx* почти пустые, при рестарте *nginx*

```
2018/07/26 09:25:04 [notice] 18566#18566: signal process started
```

Единственное что в логах насторожило, постоянное подключение с этого IP:

```
198.199.74.88 - - [26/Jul/2018:05:37:37 +0300] "GET /users/sign_in HTTP/1.1" 404 162 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
```

Если *nginx* находится на любом другом порту, например, там в **iptables** был разрешен **8099**, то все работает, но стоит порт сменить на 80, то **connection refused** и в логи **access** не пишется что было подключение.

Comment: Сейчас получил SSL сертификат, та же проблема наблюдается с 443 портом. Если переместить на порт, например, 4432, то норм, но 443 не работает.

Comment: Про адрес 198.199.74.88 nslookup сказал, что это blackbox.gitlabhosted.com.

Comment: а что будет если указать `listen <ваш ip>:80;`?

Comment: Да, я смотрел, но что это, не имею ни малейшего представления. Добавил его ip в iptables reject

Comment: @diproart тоже самое, connection refused.

Comment: это просто остатки от прошлого использования этого IP-адрес

Comment: а apache сможет работать на 80 или тоже refused?

Comment: @diproart тоже refused. Сейчас заметил еще, что и порт 8080 не работает. Я вот думаю, может это как-то связано с прошлым этого IP, и, например, хостер заблокировал эти порты. Думаю, мало вероятно, но попробую сейчас узнать у хостинга.

Comment: Блокировки вероятны, но обычно, блокируют IP.  Бывало такое на Hetzner.

Comment: @diproart, немного оффтоп, но был у меня лично случай на Digitalocean, когда всем использующим панель управления Vesta заблокировали порт 8083, на котором стоит Vesta. Это было, когда в Vesta нашли уязвимость. Сейчас написал в поддержку DO, посмотрим, что ответят.

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте настройки SELinux, возможно порт 80 не добавлен в список разрешённых:

```
semanage port -l | grep -w 80
```